# Are there algorithmic tools for computing poincare residues?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, cohomology, hypersurfaces

In Schnell's note on [Computing Picard-Fuchs Equations](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/picardfuchs.pdf) he gives a recursive method for computing residues on hypersurfaces. In short, if you have a meromorphic differential form
$$
\frac{dw}{w^k}\wedge \rho
$$
where $w$ is the local coordinate vanishing on a hypersurface $X$, you can write down a cohomologous meromorphic form
$$
\frac{d\rho}{(k-1)w^k}
$$
He claims that you can rewrite this in a manner as above. He then also claims that once $k = 1$ you can write is down as
$$
\frac{dw}{w}\wedge \alpha + \beta
$$
and then the residue of this is $\alpha$. Unfortunately, I do not see an easy way to write down equations like this in general. Are there computer algebra tools which can accomplish this for me? The main test examples I am looking at are Fermat hypersurfaces (defined by $F=0$) and the differential forms
$$
\frac{\Omega}{F}
$$
where
$$
\Omega = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i z_idz_0\wedge\cdots\wedge\hat{dz_i}\wedge\cdots\wedge dz_n
$$

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257414/de-rham-cohomology-of-x3y3-z3c-xyz-0-find-representatives/257521#257521) of mine might help. To compute in concrete examples the Jacobian ring any computer algebra tool (e.g. Macaulay2) will do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for, but, I appreciate your answer. I just want to get a better understanding of **how** to compute residues by hand just for the sake of it.